# Add Header to apex:pageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce, inline-visualforce

Is it possible to nest in a `apex:pageBlockTable` sub tables? Or to add a header to sections within the table? I feel like i should be able to just use a header tag `<h1>` type of thing but it is rejecting this and output label attributes. Is this not possible?

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock title="Disposition List" mode="inlineEdit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opportunity}" var="item">
        
            <apex:outputLabel value="Financial" style="font-weight:bold"/>****not displaying
            <apex:column value="{!item.Tax_Returns__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!item.Rent_Roll__c}"/>
            
            <apex:outputLabel value="Escrow" style="font-weight:bold"/>***not displaying
            <apex:column value="{!item.Title_Report__c}"/>
            
            <apex:outputLabel value="Something" style="font-weight:bold"/>***not displaying
            <apex:column value="{!item.Send_to_investors__c}"/>
            
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Do you have a visual representation of what is required? If you need a heading for the `pageBlockTable` you can use `pageBlockSection` above `pageBlockTable`. If you required Headers with the table you will need to create a `HTML` table using `<apex:repeat>`